# Laravel creating different views from query

Tags: php, laravel, view, left-join

I have the following query:

```
    $appointments = Appointment::orderBy('appointment', 'asc')
        ->leftJoin('appointments_labels', 'appointments_labels.id', '=', 'appointments.label_id')
        ->leftJoin('appointments_statuses', 'appointments_statuses.id', '=', 'appointments.status_id')
        ->select('appointments.id', 'appointments.appointment', 'appointments.label_id', 'appointments.status_id', 'appointments_labels.label', 'appointments_statuses.status')
        ->get();
```

What I am using this for is basically to display all my appointments like so (simplistic version of my view):

```
@foreach($appointments as $appointment)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Appointment Name</th>
            <th>Label</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>{{ $appointment->appointment }}</td>
            <td>{{ $appointment->label }}</td>
            <td>{{ $appointment->status }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
@endforeach
```

This will display all my appointments, including the correct label name and status name from the proper database tables. My wish is, to be able to create a view like so:

```
@foreach($appointments as $appointment)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ $appointment->label }}</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>

    @foreach($appointment->appointments as $label)

        <tr>
            <td>{{ $label->appointment }}</td>
            <td>{{ $label->status }}</td>
        </tr>

    @endforeach

    </table>
@endforeach
```

So it lists the first label inluding all appointments which have that particular label, and then the next label with it's appointments, and so on. Is that simply possible with my above query? Or should I create relations in my models instead and work from there? If there is a better way to do all this ofcourse, I'm all ears.

Below is an export of my database tables for a better understanding of my code perhaps.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `appointment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `label_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments_labels` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments_statuses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use laravel collections `groupBy`:

Import it in your header:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

Then:

```
$appointments = Appointment::orderBy('appointment', 'asc')
    ->leftJoin('appointments_labels', 'appointments_labels.id', '=', 'appointments.label_id')
    ->leftJoin('appointments_statuses', 'appointments_statuses.id', '=', 'appointments.status_id')
    ->select('appointments.id', 'appointments.appointment', 'appointments.label_id', 'appointments.status_id', 'appointments_labels.label', 'appointments_statuses.status')
    ->get();

$appointments = Collection::make($appointments)->groupBy('label');
var_dump($appointments);
```

Comment: Awesome, will give this a go and see if I can get with this what I need, thanks :)

Comment: Couldn't get this to work, couldn't figure it out. So I ended up creating relations using hasMany and belongsTo in my models, and creating the views from there. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: Strange, I'm going to test with your code, I just tested on one of my simple table, without joins..

Comment: No worries, I just never worked with collections yet and it just didn't work out for me, so it's really my fault :)