# Convert Laravel Query builder to Eloquent builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Because `get()` function of Query builder returns an array while I need A collection, is there a way to convert Laravel Query Builder to Eloquent Builder?

```
$query_builder = DB::table('table1');

// different than
$eloquent_builder = Table1Model::select()
```

Comment: You can create a collection from an array: `Collection::make($query_builder)`. Here is a usage sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449387/laravel-creating-different-views-from-query/33449507#33449507

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laravel ships with a `collect` helper to convert an array to a collection:

```php
$collection = collect(DB::table('table1')->get());
```

There's [a proposal on Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10478) to have the next version of Laravel return collection instances from the query builder's `get` method.

Comment: As in laravel 5.4 and 5.5 Query Builder (`DB::table`) returns `collection`